# Why am I required to buy something on BrickLink before I am allowed to sell?

Tags: bricklink

Why does BrickLink require you to purchase something before you are able to sell? I already have too many Lego bricks and I'm trying to get rid of a lot of them, so I'm not trying to buy more. I'm just trying to sell all the characters I have, but it won't let me.

Why is this policy in place?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It’s not perfect, but it’s their way of finding reputable sellers. Any purchase counts so you can just buy 5 more cheap minifigs.

Comment: I would add to this that BrickLink has an ongoing problem with scammers. Some of them have stolen thousands of dollars from buyers. The only reliable way they can discourage most of these scam accounts is to force sellers to "invest" in the site. Place a few small orders and you will be fine. Just turn around and resell the items, or give them to charity. Buyers will also trust you much more if you have some feedback already, so it will benefit you as well.

Comment: Thanks for your advice I will think about it however im most likely just gonna try to sell them on ebay or find someone who may be interested.